# Laravel: Rename route names for resource routes

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I want to use a different (plural) model name for my route names, because my url is in a different language.

I can Achieve it with [Restful Naming Resource Routes](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/controllers#restful-naming-resource-routes)

```
Route::resource('/foo', BarController::class)->parameters([
    'foo' => 'bar',
])->names([
    'index' => 'bar.index',
    'create' => 'bar.create',
    'store' => 'bar.store',
    'show' => 'bar.show',
    'edit' => 'bar.edit',
    'update' => 'bar.update',
    'destroy' => 'bar.destroy',
]);
```

But.. I would have to do it for every resource route:

```
Route::resource('/usuarios', UserController::class)->parameters([
    'usuarios' => 'user',
])->names([
    'index' => 'user.index',
    'create' => 'user.create',
    'store' => 'user.store',
    'show' => 'user.show',
    'edit' => 'user.edit',
    'update' => 'user.update',
    'destroy' => 'user.destroy',
]);
```

How could I make this DRY?

Answer (score 1):

You can extract that part into a function.

```
function routeNames($model)
{
    return array_map(
        fn ($n) => "{$model}.{$n}",
        ['index', 'create', 'store', 'show', 'edit', 'update', 'destroy']
    );
}


Route::resource('/usuarios', UserController::class)->parameters([
    'usuarios' => 'user',
])->names(routeNames('user'));
```